# How to make a pastebin folder visible to the public?

Tags: pastebin

How to make a pastebin folder visible to the public? I have a pastebin pro account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's not possible.**

From [pastebin faq](https://pastebin.com/faq#ff):

> **Who can see my folders?**
>   If a user creates a folder, and puts 'public' pastes in that folder, to others, those pastes will show up in the root folder of that Pastebin account. However, for the logged in user who created the folder, those pastes will show in the folder they were put in.
>
> *Note: Folders are meant to organize your own private Pastebin better and are only visible to the logged in user who created them.*

- **The *note* is actually your answer**, but its good to know the overall of what folders mean in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com).